# Hex converts to wrong decimal

Tags: arrays, hex, decimal

I am trying to read/write hexadecimals into a 2D integer array for my program, but there are issues with some hexadecimals.

When I input `272cf50` it accurately turns into `41078608` in the array and I have no problems.

But when I input `ffff0000000` it turns into `-268435456` instead of its decimal equivalent: `17591917608960`.

Because of this when I try to check if `ffff0000000` already exists in the array it says it doesn't even though I wrote it into the array. I am confused about why this is happening and how I can fix it.

This is the code:

```
bool inCache(unsigned long addy, unsigned long blockid, unsigned long setidx, int size, int** cache, int lps){
    //find set index
    //find easier way
    int i=0;
    while(cache[i][0]!=setidx){
        i++;
    }
    
    //check if set contains blockid
    for(int j=0; j<lps; j++){
    
        if(cache[i+j][2]==1 && cache[i+j][1]==blockid){
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    //not in cache
    return false;
}
void read(unsigned long addy, unsigned long blockid, unsigned long setidx, int size, int** cache, int lps){
    unsigned long x = blockid;
    bool e = inCache(addy,blockid,setidx,size,cache,lps);
    if(e==true){
        ch++;
    }else{
        cm++;
        mr++;
        
        //set x in cache
        newWrite(addy,x,setidx,size,cache,lps);
    }
}
void newWrite(unsigned long addy, unsigned long blockid, unsigned long setidx, int size, int** cache, int lps){
    //check if already loaded in cache
    bool e = inCache(addy,blockid,setidx,size,cache,lps);
    if(e!=true){
        //load the block into chosen cache line
        
        //find the setidx
        int i=0;
        while(cache[i][0]!=setidx){
            i++;
        }
        
        //go thru set and put into first available cacheline
        for(int j=0; j<lps; j++){
            if(cache[i+j][2]==0){
                cache[i+j][2]=1;
                cache[i+j][1]=blockid;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        //if all cachelines are full, put into least recent cacheline
        cache[i][1]=blockid;
    }
}
```

This is the specific example:

```
0x1: R 0xffff0000000
0x2: R 0xffff0000000
```

In my particular example, for the first line the read function gets called and since the value is not in the array(cache) it calls the newWrite funciton to add it to the array. When it is added to the cache is when it converts to `-268435456`. Then, for the second line when the read function checks if the value is in the array it returns false instead of true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of an *integer overflow*. Precisely what happened, was that the inputted number was interpreted as [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The number was so long that the [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) got flipped. Indeed,

> 0xFFFF0000000 - 2⁴⁴ = -268435456

which is where that mysterious number came from.

Surely the best way to manage this situation is to keep care that the variables used can hold numbers that big, or to reject too large values.

EDIT with more information

The code shows that the array’s signature is `int **`. This should be unsigned too in order to make the comparison to work. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int a = 0xffff0000000;
  unsigned long b = 0xffff0000000;
  printf("%d\n",a==b);
  /*  the number zero (meaning "false") is printed */
}
```

Comment: How could I fix this because my variables are all unsigned longs so I assumed they could hold values this large, and I cannot reject any values in my program?

Comment: Well, it would certainly help, if you posted the actual code by which the issue came about.